# shorter version of jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, there is no problem, but i just got curious how to shorten this function.

```
$('input#sum').blur(function() {
        var fieldVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(formatNumber(fieldVal));
});
```

I get field value on blur modify it with formatNumber custom function and return. But is see I have 3 selectors there, is there a way to shorten this?

Format number function is:

```
function formatNumber(input) {
 // modify and return input
}
```

Comment: You only have one selector there and two DOMElement to jQuery set converts. Anyway, why do you want to shorten it?

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I just asked about possible optimization, no special need for shortening

Comment: The overhead of `$(domElement)` is nearly not noticeable, as it won't involve any DOM traversing. (it is about 2 function invocation, 1 type test, 1 property existing test, and 3 assignments) [git: jquery/core/init](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/core/init.js#L96). So for your code snipped it is nothing to worry about. the `.val` like descriptor in your accepted answer is a bigger problem there, even if it would also not be noticeable for a simple `blur`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input#sum').blur(function() {
    this.value = formatNumber(this.value);
});
//1 selector!
```

I don't even see why you would need jQuery there. **[Don't abuse jQuery](https://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery) when you [don't actually need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).**

Take a look at [jQuery's source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js) at line 7294:

```
val: function( value ) {
    var hooks, ret, isFunction,
        elem = this[0];

    if ( !arguments.length ) {
        if ( elem ) {
            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

            if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
                return ret;
            }

            ret = elem.value;

            return typeof ret === "string" ?
                // handle most common string cases
                ret.replace(rreturn, "") :
                // handle cases where value is null/undef or number
                ret == null ? "" : ret;
        }
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```

If you get rid of the hook part which simply replace newlines into `\r\n` and ignore the bottom special `null` case, the only thing left is just `ret = elem.value`. Now you know that you can safely use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Comment: I agree. But if jQuery is already available, why *not* use it? The performance difference in this case isn't even worth thinking about.

Comment: @George - Do you really think `$(this).val(formatNumber($(this).val()))` is better than `this.value = formatNumber(this.value)`?

Comment: No, but I didn't suggest that.

Comment: @George - In most cases jQuery is definitely better because it increases readability and efficiency. However in this case, such simple task is easy to be handled by just a simple statement. I don't see any reason over-complicating it.

Comment: Changed accepted answer to this. This one is simple and elegant. Sometimes I just forget JavaScript native functions when I use jQuery from day to day.

Answer (score 3):

You sure can, by passing a function to `val()`:

```
$('input#sum').blur(function() {
    $(this).val(function(_,v){ return formatNumber(v); });
});
```

**Documentation**

- [`val()` - function](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input#sum').blur(function() {
        $(this).val(formatNumber($(this).val()));
});
```

Doesn't solve your selectors problem, but it's shorter..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put formatted value in `.val()`. And use id selector `$('#sum')` instead of `$('input#sum')` directly, but make sure that you have unique id through out the html page.

```
$('#sum').blur(function() {
        $(this).val(formatNumber($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: You changed the semantics. Maybe Roo only wants to apply the handler if the element's tag name is `input`?

Comment: Yeah quite possible, but if OP has id of the element then why to use other parameter for jquery selector?

Comment: There are situation where this is important (Imagine a common form that has - depending on the situation - some elements not editable). You might have for css and/or for jQuery two selectors `span#sum`, `input#sum`  and depending if it is a `span` or and `input` it is displayed differently and/or behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal Javascript and create a formatNumber function extends String (or another type).

```js
// Your function
String.prototype.formatNumber = function () {
 // return the modified value of this
 return this;
};

$('selector').blur(function() {
    this.value = this.value.formatNumber();
});
```

**UPDATED:**
Better you can extends the HTMLInputElement and add the function to it.

```js
// Extends the HTMLInputElement
HTMLInputElement.prototype.formatNumber = function(){
 // Your function here
 this.value = this.value.toFixed(0); // An example
};

$('input').blur(function() {
   this.formatNumber(); // 1 line
});
```